# Setting User Permission via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, pnp-powershell

I am attempting to write a script where if there is a user in SharePoint Online that has Full Control, that it gets updated to a new Full Control - No Subwebs permission level.

Despite that it saying it has made the necessary change, when I go to check in SharePoint, the permission stays the same. The permission level is created successfully and I can get it working for the group side of my script. Just not for users that are explicitly added.

It also for some reason won't work recursively through the subsites. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#Connect to Site Collection
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://foo.sharepoint.com/sites/testmodernsitecollection/ -UseWebLogin

#Get All Subsites
$Sites = Get-PnPSubWebs
 
#Create New Permission Level by cloning Full Control and excluding ManageSubWebs.

Add-PnPRoleDefinition -RoleName "Full Control - No Subwebs" -Clone "Full Control" -Exclude ManageSubwebs -Description "Full Control - No Subwebs"

Foreach ($Site in $Sites)
    { 
        $Groups = Get-PnPGroup
        $Users = Get-PnPUser -WithRightsAssigned -Web $Site

#Loop for setting User Permissions
        
        Foreach ($User in $Users | Where-Object {$_.PrincipalType -eq "User"}){
            $UserPermission = Get-PnPUser -Identity $User.LoginName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($UserPermission.RoleTypeKind -eq "Administrator")
            {
                Set-PnPWebPermission -Identity $User -RemoveRole "Full Control" -AddRole "Full Control - No Subwebs"
                
            }
            Write-host "Updated Permission Level for $($User.Title) at $($Site.Title)"         
        }

#Loop for setting Group Permissions
        Foreach ($Group in $Groups | Where-Object {$_.PrincipalType -eq "SharePointGroup"}) {
            $GroupPermission = Get-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $Group.Title -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($GroupPermission.RoleTypeKind -eq "Administrator")
            {
                Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $Group -RemoveRole "Full Control" -AddRole "Full Control - No Subwebs" 
            } 
            Write-host "Updated Permission Level for $($Group.Title) at $($Site.Title)" -f Green  
        }

    }
    Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

**1.Create a custom Permission Level**

Click on **Site permissions** under the **settings** menu >> click **Advanced permission settings** >> click **Permission Levels** >> click on **Add a Permission Level**
[image]
[image]

**2.Run the below PnP powershell**

```
$SiteURL = "https://test.spo.com/sites/echocc"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

Set-PnPWebPermission -User 'echo@test.spo.com' -AddRole 'Full Control-No Subsites permission' -RemoveRole 'Full Control'
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To work with sub-sites/webs with UniqeRoleAssigments **recursively**, I would do the followings:

1. Get all **subwebs/sub-sites** recursively in the site collection context

```
$Sites=Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse -Includes HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```

2. Before working with each subweb, connect again in the subweb' context

```
Foreach ($Site in $Sites)
    { 
        #get subweb/sub-site context
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.Url -UseWebLogin

        $Groups = Get-PnPGroup
        $Users = Get-PnPUser -WithRightsAssigned -Web $Site
    ...
    #code for other processing
   }
```